# LogDNA only stores the last month of logs

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, rsyslog

I am trying this logging solution for my whole infrastructure on AWS (ec2, rds, docker and so on).

The solution is clean and works pretty great. Although, it seems to store **only the last month of logs**.

As I care more about patching logs, I could work around this issue by getting the patching history out of the LogDNA S3 bucket, and saving it somewhere else, but that would not be trivial.

Could you, specialist in LogDNA, confirm that it is not possible to increase the log window to more than 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in discussion the retention period you are better off talking to the sales team.  Pulling the patching history out of your S3 archived logs should not be too bad because LogDNA archives are in a json format, but it would require custom work.